# how to add a database field in the c# code without using stored procedures in a disconnected architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I need to create login page in asp.net where i have to create 3 user access levels such as

users who can view there email and updates 
superusers who can view there email, updates and also delete some users
admin who can view all and delete superusers as well.

my login page has 
username
password and login button

when the user/admin/superuser clicks on the button it should automatically redirect him depending on the user levels.

i have a database of username, password, userid, useraccesstype, email.
my problem here is i am not getting how to write the if commands basing on the useraccesstype in a disconnected architecture of database and also without using stored procedures.

```
 String Uid = TextBox1.Text;
 String Pwd = TextBox2.Text;

 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Sun-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dts;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=********;");
 SqlDataAdapter da;
 da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select userid,password,useraccesstype from Table2 WHERE userid = " + Uid + " and password ='" + Pwd + "'", con);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet("Table2");
 da.Fill(ds, "Table2");

 if (Uid == "userid" && Pwd == "password")
 {
     if (uzrtype3 = "componentadmin")
     {
         Response.Redirect("userpage.aspx");
     }
     if (uzrtype = "user")
     {
         Response.Redirect("register.aspx");
     }
 }
 else
 {
     Label123.Text = "Sorry, user not recognized - please try again";
 }
```

Comment: Whatever else you do : ***please*** learn about SQL injection; your code is horribly unsafe at the moment. As in: anybody *without even needing an account* could destroy your DB with that code. Also, salted hashes instead of passwords. (goes back to read the question)

Comment: @Mark I'm glad you beat me to that because i'm having difficulty using my iPhone! Also please don't get in the habit of calling things TextBox1, TextBox2 etc. It's lazy and you'll end up cursing yourself.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? I'm very unsure what you mean by "add a database field" in the title (and it isn't clear in the question), and it isn't clear what stored procedures have to do with the question. What bit are you currently stuck on? It seems to me like you are asking how to look inside the DataSet - I which case ds.Tables[0].Rows would be a place to start (although: using a DataSet at all here seems overkill). Can you confirm: is the issue here simply that you want to check for a match, and if so, read the useraccesstype value?

Comment: Jumping in for Oded: [Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 1):

Reading between the lines, I *think* you are asking "how t get the useraccesstype"? If so *with the current code*, maybe:

```
if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1) {
    // match
    var accessType = ({appropriate cast here})ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["useraccesstype"];
} else {
    // no match
}
```

However! I would do it a different way, solving the various parameter issues and making it much safer - using "dapper-dot-net" for convenience (google it):

```
string userid = ....
string password = ...
var row = con.Query(
   "Select useraccesstype from Table2 WHERE userid = @userid and password = @password",
   new { userid, password }).FirstOrDefault();
if(row == null) {
    // no match
} else {
    var accessType = ({some cast here})row.useraccesstype;
}
```

The salted hashing of passwords is also something you should look into.

No point returning the userid/password : you already know those. You could also use ExecuteScalar, but then you need to handle the parameters yourself.